# Laravel ReactJS - Infinite compiling after import CSS file into component

Tags: reactjs, laravel, webpack, sass

I am creating a web app with Laravel and ReactJS, I mentioned scss files in root/resources/scss like `style.scss` which are compiled by `webpack.min.js` to root/public/css and will become `style.css`.

```
mix.sass('resources/sass/style.scss', 'public/css');
```

When I import style.css into React component like `import 'style.css'` then infinite compiling starts happening.

But when I comment on the code of compiling the scss file to normal CSS file and then `import 'style.css';` then everything is good.

```
// mix.sass('resources/sass/style.scss', 'public/css');
```

I want the `style.scss` file to compile only when I change to that file which is not possible if I already commented on the compilation code in webpack.min.js